# Issue With Wrapping Text Around Images in IE

Tags: css, image, internet-explorer, css-float, word-wrap

I have a simple issues that's driving me crazy, I'm trying to wrap text around an image, and it works fine in every browser but IE. Because the picture is bigger then the paragraph, the following paragraphs starts at the bottom of the image. Take a look at the pictures.

[image: image-wrapping]

CSS used for aligning picture

```
mg.centered, .aligncenter, div.aligncenter {
display: block;
margin-left: auto;
margin-right: auto;
}

img.alignright {
    padding: 4px;
    margin: 0 0 2px 7px;
    display: inline;
    float: right;
    }

img.alignleft {
    padding: 4px;
    margin: 0 7px 2px 0;
    display: inline;
    float: left;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Try applying the following to your images:

```
display: inline-block;
zoom: 1; /* IE7 hack */
*display: inline; /* IE6 hack */
```

You cannot apply `padding` or `margin` to a `inline` element.

Comment: Recomendations for CSS hacks have to be along with warnings like: "This is not valid CSS" and "It's better to use a separated stylesheet for this and use conditional comments to inlcude the styles."